# Weld CDI does not inject if combined with RestEasy

Tags: jboss, jax-rs, cdi, resteasy, weld

I'm trying to use CDI (Weld) in a Jax-RS (RestEasy) service on a JBoss 7.1.1.
Injection works fine if I use it in e.g. a simple servlet, but as soon as I do the same in my Jax-RS service it remains `null`. No error, just no injection. When reading [the JBoss RestEasy CDI Integration page](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/CDI.html) it all looks so easy.

Some things I tried:

1. Use RestEasy 3.0.9.Final with compile dependency
2. Use RestEasy 2.3.2.Final with provided dependency
3. Add RestEasy 3.0.9.Final as a JBoss module and use that instead of the original 2.3.2.Final
4. Add dependency on resteasy-cdi.jar (in both compile and provided variants)
5. Add the manifest dependency as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068148/resteasy-cdi-getting-duplicate-context-initialization-parameter-resteasy-inje)
6. Empty web.xml and one filled simular to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19879783/jax-rs-jboss-7-1-1-resteasy-nullpointexception-using-cdi?rq=1)
7. Add `@RequestScoped` or `@Named` to the REST service so it would be picked up by Weld

Non of the above (and some other wild tries) leads to anything.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting up your rest application like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654634/java-ee7-javax-ws-rs-injection-of-ejb-in-rest-resource/26660018

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution for this issue myself. Knowing the solution, it turns out I didn't show the complete picture in my question.

In my XxxApplication (extending `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`) I added a new XxxService instance (!!) to the singleton list.

And in my XxxService I did a `new B()`, where class B has an `@Inject C` which is the one remaining `null`.

It turned out that instantiating both the XxxService and class B caused the problem.

When adding XxxService.class to the classes list in XxxApplication (instead of adding `new XxxService()` to the singleton list) and using `@Inject B` in the XxxService, all injections work properly, including the `@Inject C` in B.